# Is "return this" necessary after every method in a Backbone view?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Is "return this" necessary at the end of every method within a Backbone view?

```
render: function() {
this.editElem();
// I realize it wouldn't be necessary here, but...
},

renderElem: function() {
this.$el.addClass('foobar');
return this // is this one necessary?
},
```

**EDIT**
What about this example?

```
render: function() {
this.editElem();
},

renderElem: function() {
this.$el.addClass('foobar');
return this;
},
```

Comment: Personally, I don't return `this` on **every** method.. just in `render()` and because it is a community-standard.

Comment: Removing 'return this;' from render caused all sorts of crazy, fun problems, but removing it from editElem didn't seem to have an effect.

Comment: Backbone never calls your render methods, so nothing forces you to follow that convention, but your own code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To quote what the official [documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#View-render) says

> A good convention is to return this at the end of render to enable chained calls.

So no it's not necessary but it's probably a good idea.

In general you will see it in methods that modify/render the view's `el`, by returning `this` in one of those methods you are making it easier to access the view's `el`, so that you can now do something like

```
$("#somelist").append(myview.render().el);
```

instead of doing it in two lines like

```
myview.render();
$("#somelist").append(myview.el);
```

Comment: Ah, so removing the this.render; in editElem didn't seem to have an effect, but it could if I did something like this.

Comment: Most likely, and the same is probably true of your `render` method in that it is probably being used in such a manner.

Answer (score 8):

I haven't used Backbone, so I'm not sure if it is required (probably not), but you'll typically see that pattern used so that you can "chain" function calls together. It's called a [fluent interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface).

With this pattern, for example, you can write compact code like:

```
myVariable.editElem().somethingElse().anotherMethod();
```

Comment: Thanks for the link, I had heard of chained methods, but never 'fluent interface'.